# in Hapi I get h.file is not a function

Tags: node.js, hapi

Im running the latest version of hapi but when I try to server static files I get the error h.file is not a function.  I have inert installed.  Here is the relevant code and my package.json

package.json

```
{
  "name": "node",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "import_data.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ag-grid-angular": "^19.1.2",
    "ag-grid-community": "^19.1.4",
    "hapi": "^17.8.1",
    "inert": "^5.1.2",
    "npm": "^6.4.1",
    "sqlite3": "^4.0.4"
  }
}
```

route code

```
// Create a server with a host and port
const server=Hapi.server({
    host:'localhost',
    port:8000,
    routes: {
        files: {
            relativeTo: Path.join(__dirname, 'mibfiles')
        }
    }
});

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/mibfiles/{mibname}',
    handler: function(request, h) {
        return h.file('mibfiles/' + request.params.mibname + ".mib")
    }
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forgot to register the inert object in hapi
await server.register(require('inert'));

Comment: This was it for me as well. It was at the top line of the HAPI tutorial and I missed it.